# R word search algorithm

Tags: r

i want to search columns 2 and 3 for the word "is"
which should return 1, 2, and 3.
what code should i use? 
thanks in advance.

```
c1  c2                  c3    
1   a dog is barking    I am late
2   it is raining       I will run
3   we are eating       this is fun
4   I am sleepy         maybe tomorrow
5   later tonight       we all laugh

grepl("is", "file.csv", ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE, fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)
```

to no avail. thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! What code did you try that didn't work or what resources did you research that did not turn up that _kinda_ solved the problem but didn't fully solve it? SO is (generally) not a code-writing service and I suspect this is well-traveled territory on SO. Perhaps a supplementary question is: what would you use to find substrings in a plain character vector? If you can't answer that, then you likely should do a bit more research.

Comment: grepl("is", "file.csv", ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE, fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)

Comment: but did not work

Comment: that belongs in the question and also suggests you may want to invest some more time in some basic R tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `paste` to make columns c2 and c3 into a single list of strings and then test for the presence of "is" using `grep`

```
grep("\\bis\\b", paste(df$c2, df$c3))
```